# In different situations during creating shared libraries, what functions can be called with the lib?

Tags: function, gcc, shared-libraries

I have read related tutorials regarding shared and static libraries, such as:

["Creating a shared and static library with the gnu compiler [gcc]"](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html)

["Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries"](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

However, unfortunately, all examples they used are one function one .c file.

I have two questions:

(1) If I have one file with two more functions, such as  example1.c

```
void ctest11(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }

void ctest12(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }
```

After compiling exmaple1.c to libexample1.so, can I call ctest11 and ctest12 in it?

(2) If I have one file with two more functions, one of them is a main function, such as  example2.c

```
void ctest21(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }

void main(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }
```

After compiling exmaple2.c to libexample2.so, is it the same as to compile one .c file with only ctest21 function?

(3) If I have one file example3.c and exmaple4.c
The funcion in example3.c will use the function in example4.c
For example:
example3.c

```
void ctest31(int *i)
{ *i = ctest41(2,3); }
```

example4.c

```
int ctest41(int a, int b)
{ return a+b; }
```

When I compile example2.c and example3.c to libexample23.so, can I call both ctest31 and ctest41?

But if gcc example2.c example3.o to libexample2.so, I guess I can only call ctest31?

Comment: Are you sure to ask the real question ? What is your true motivation for that ? (why a `main` inside `libexample2`?)

Answer (score 1):

You should look inside (and build) some existing free software library, compile it, and study its code and building process.

In general, a shared object can be made from several C source files `src1sh.c` and `src2sh.c` .... Very often, the compilation is driven by a builder program, usually [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

First, you need to compile every source file of the shared object as [position-independent-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (PIC) e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC src1sh.c -c -o src1sh.pic.o
gcc -Wall -fPIC src2sh.c -c -o src2sh.pic.o
```

<sup>You probably want to add `-g` to the `gcc` flags for debugging purposes. Once your program and shared objects are bug free because you have debugged them with `gdb` and `valgrind`, pass `-O2` to `gcc` to have them optimized.</sup>

Then you need to link all these PIC object files into a single shared object (a `*.so` file), like

```
gcc -shared src1sh.pic.o src2sh.pic.o -o shared.so
```

If your intent is to make a shared library call it `lib*.so` e.g. `libfoo.so` and refer to it as `-lfoo` flag to the linking `gcc` command using your shared library.

Notice that linking a shared object may also link other shared libraries, so you could do

```
gcc -shared src1sh.pic.o src2sh.pic.o -lsome -o shared.so
```

to link some `libsome.so` into your `shared.so`

You usually don't compile a shared object containing a `main` (remember that `main` is a very special function, described specifically in the *C* standard, and called from the startup code `crt*.o` linked by `gcc` into every program); this is nearly non-sense (like your `libexample2.so`). Your `main` is defined in your program (and you don't need PIC code for your program executable). If your program is made from source files `src1pr.c` and `src2pr.c` (which defines `main`) you first compile them as

```
gcc -Wall src1pr.c -c -o src1pr.o
gcc -Wall src2pr.c -c -o src2pr.o
```

and you link them all with e.g.

```
gcc src1pr.o src2pr.o -o prog -lshared
```

where `-lshared` refers to a shared library `libshared.so` (you probably want to compile and link your program files with `-g` for debugging information, and you may want to pass additional `-I` flags for include directories, and `-L` flags for library directories, e.g. `-L.` to search library in the current directory ...)

There is a way to **dynamically link at runtime** some shared object, notably for having [plugins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29). You then want to use the [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & `dlsym` functons for that (and you usually want to link your main program with `-rdynamic` flag).

You can call (from your program) any *visible* function inside a shared object. You may want to play with the `visibility` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to e.g. restrict the visibility of some function inside your shared object. You might perhaps want to later use the `constructor` attribute, for a function inside a shared object to be called early at initialization time (if it is a plugin, at its `dlopen` time).

Read [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [Levine's "Linkers and Loaders" book](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) for more. Linux shared objects (and relocatable object `*.o`, and executable binaries) are in [Executable & Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (ELF is an industry standard). Some further details are described in the [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (and notably the ABI supplement for your processor, e.g. [AMD64 ABI supplement](http://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/images/d/de/System_V_Application_Binary_Interface_AMD64_Architecture_Processor_Supplement.pdf)).

PS. You really want a builder like GNU *make* to combine all these steps, so read its documentation. You might want to pass `-v` to `gcc` to understand what it is doing...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Basile' great explanation. 
From 
what I understand, related to my questions,

(a) For my first question (1), there are multiple functions in one object file. I can call ctest11 and ctest12 in libexample1.so

I may set visibility to the functions in libexample1.so.

(b) For my third question (3), the firs scenario is related to create a library from two object files. I can call any functions in the files.
The second scenario is related to create a library and link with another library. I can call any functions in the libraries, including the linking library.

(3) I still do not understand the situations with a main function.
You said, "You usually don't compile a shared object containing a main; this is nearly non-sense (like your libexample2.so). "

I knew it is non-sense. But if I do not want to change the program file, and want to compile it to a library, say, in example2.c, I compile it to example2.so, and want to call the function ctest21.
Can I do that?

example2.c

```
void ctest21(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }

void main(int *i)
{ *i = 5; }
```

I compile it to a library.

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall example2.c
gcc -shared -o libexample2.so example2.o
```

I think I can call crest21 function in example2.o. But the main function is useless. 
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why do you need a `main` function in your `libexample2.so`? What are the real motivations behind your question? Why do you want to do all that? (And `main` *cannot* take one `int *i` formal argument, per the C standard! You could compile `example2.c` with e.g. `-Dmain=foo` to "rename" `main` as something else...).

Comment: Sorry. the tutorial in http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html  uses void ctest1(int *i). Anyway, I just wanted to know if I put main in it, what will happen? No motivation except I wanted to know result under extreme situations.

Comment: And I am curious about the inside mechanism to make a library. For example, how to organize the information, how to find the entry point to a function. Is there any good tutorial on that? Thanks.

Comment: Each function in C has a single entry point. That starting instruction is bound by the linker to the name of the function. And the Yolinux tutorial don't have `main` in shared libraries...

Comment: The yolinux tutorial uses void ctest1(int *i). I came up my own idea to include main() to know what will happen. Thank you very much.