# gcc: error: libhello.so: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc

here is my code:

```
// hello.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return (0);
}
```

i type `gcc hello.c -o -shared libhello.so` in terminal and get:

```
gcc: error: libhello.so: No such file or directory
```

**question:** How to compile .c file to .so file with **one command line**

**update:** if i fix it with `gcc hello.c -shared -o libhello.so`, but i just some confused, why the error message is "gcc: error: libhello.so: No such file or directory", not "gcc: error: libhello.so: No such file or directory '-shared'"

Comment: `gcc hello.c -o -shared libhello.so` means "compile file `hello.c` and `libhello.so`, and put result in file `-shared`". As output file would be created during compilation, compiler does not issue warning that it is missing. Existence of source files, however, is necessary for compilation to succeed, so error message is issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, a shared library should contain [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). So compile it with

```
gcc  -Wall -fPIC -shared -O -g hello.c -o libhello.so
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917721/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508185/841108) answers.

And a shared object should (nearly) *never* have a `main` function.

PS. Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot!

Comment: Any suggestions on the order for creating a DLL?

Comment: DLL are Windows specific. You need to read the documentation (notably of your linker).

Comment: Let's say it is generic Shared Library. For instance, should I use the optimization flags both when creating the o file and the Shared Library or only on one of the steps? Thank You.

Comment: Better use both. But certainly for the `.o` file.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the output file must directly follow `-o`. Try this:

```
gcc hello.c -shared -o libhello.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do this. But maybe `gcc hello.c -shared -o libhello.so`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gcc hello.c
```

This command generates `hello.c` directly into the final binary executable with the default name `a.out`
Execution is done with

```
. /a
```

If you want to give a name instead of `a.out`, use

```
 gcc -o hello hello.c
```

To generate hello and execute it, use

```
. /hello
```